# Find all objects of a certain class that do not have any active links with other objects

Tags: python, django

I have a class `A` which is used as a Foreign Key in many other classes.

```
class A(models.Model):
  pass

class B(models.Model):
  a: A = ForeignKey(A)

class C(models.Model):
  other_name: A = ForeignKey(A)
```

Now I have a database with a huge table of `A` objects and many classes like `B` and `C` who reference `A` (say potentially dozens). In this table, there are many objects (100k+) and I want to clean up all objects that are not actively referenced by other objects with a Foreign Key. For example, `object 1` of class `A` is not referenced by class `B` and `C`.

How would I do this? I already came up with the following code:

```
a_list: list = list()
classes: list[tuple] = [(B, "a"), (C, "other_name")]

for cl, field in classes:
  field_object: Field = cl._meta.get_field(field)
  for obj in cl.objects.all():
    a: A = field_object.value_from_object(obj)
    a_list.append(a)

to_remove: list[A] = [a for a in A.objects.all() if a not in a_list]
for a in to_remove():
  a.remove()
```

This leaves me with a few questions:

- What if I don't know the full list of classes and fields (the case since it is a large group)?
- Is this the most efficient way to do this for a large table with many unrelated objects (say 95%)? I guess I can optimize this a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with:

```
A.objects.filter(b=None, c=None).delete()
```

This will make proper JOINs and thus determine the items in a single querying, without having to fetch all other model records from the database.

But this will be expensive anyway, since the triggers are done by Django that will thus "collect" all `A` objects.

If you do not know what is referencing `A`, you can work with the meta of the model, so:

```
from django.db.models.fields.reverse_related import OneToOneRel

fields = {
    f.related_query_name: None
    for f in A._meta.get_fields()
    if isinstance(f, ManyToOneRel)
}

A.objects.filter(**fields).delete()
```

This will look for all `ForeignKey`s and `OneToOneField`s from other models that target (directly) the `A` model, then make `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s and filter on `NULL`, and then delete those.

I would advise to first inspect `A.objects.filter(**fields)` however, and make sure you do not remove any items that are still necessary.

Comment: Seems like an elegant solution, but could it be that there is an issue in your fields definition? It always returns None: None. I tried with ForeignObjectRel instead of ManyToOneRel but that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @takje: normally that should work, you did not specify `related_name='+'` somewhere? Because then querying in reverse is not possible.

Comment: No, it is somehow on the if construction that it fails. I can get all the fields. When I just print the f.__class__.__name__ it shows the right classes. However, the if only returns the id field.

Comment: I think I see the problem. This returns the ID field of those respective related objects and hence the related_query_name is non-existent.

Comment: So, since the result returns the ID field from the right class, an approximate solution is to use f.name rather than f.related_query_name. This solved my issue but still is a risk for custom related names.

Comment: @takje: no `f.related_query_name` is the name of the relation in reverse. I tested this with a field with a `OneToOneField` at the other side. You thus need to obtain the relations that point *to* `A`, and then use the `related_query_name` to filter *from* `A`.